# how to rename multidimensional arrays with specified keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to rename all array keys from the first dimension in this form

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname17
                [1] => lastname17
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname7
                [1] => lastname7
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname18
                [1] => lastname18
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname12
                [1] => lastname12
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname3
                [1] => lastname3
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [5] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname13
                [1] => lastname13
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname11
                [1] => lastname11
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname19
                [1] => lastname19
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname9
                [1] => lastname9
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname8
                [1] => lastname8
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [10] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname10
                [1] => lastname10
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname2
                [1] => lastname2
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname4
                [1] => lastname4
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname16
                [1] => lastname16
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname15
                [1] => lastname15
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [15] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname1
                [1] => lastname1
            )

        [16] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname6
                [1] => lastname6
            )

        [17] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname20
                [1] => lastname20
            )

        [18] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname14
                [1] => lastname14
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname5
                [1] => lastname5
            )

    )

)
```

using the php code below. When I run it I get undefined index in all new array keys am trying to remain the keys from chunked array into.
`"location1","location2","location3","location4","location5","location6","location"`

```
<?php

$centers = array("location1","location2","location3","location4","location5","location6","location");
$row = '';
$filename =  'arrays.csv';
     $handle = fopen($filename, "r");      //Open file for reading
     if($handle){
       while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, ",")) !== FALSE){
        $state[] = $data;
         shuffle($state);
     }

        $newarray = array_chunk($state, 5, true);
        foreach($newarray as $key){
        foreach($centers as $newkey){
          $newarray[$newkey] = $centers[$newkey];

        }
}
      echo "<pre>";
     print_r($newarray);

   }
   ?>
```

edit: Expected output should look like this

```
Array
(
[location1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname17
                [1] => lastname17
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname7
                [1] => lastname7
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname18
                [1] => lastname18
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname12
                [1] => lastname12
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname3
                [1] => lastname3
            )

    )

[location2] => Array
    (
        [5] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname13
                [1] => lastname13
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname11
                [1] => lastname11
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname19
                [1] => lastname19
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname9
                [1] => lastname9
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname8
                [1] => lastname8
            )

    )

[location3] => Array
    (
        [10] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname10
                [1] => lastname10
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname2
                [1] => lastname2
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname4
                [1] => lastname4
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname16
                [1] => lastname16
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname15
                [1] => lastname15
            )

    )

[location4] => Array
    (
        [15] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname1
                [1] => lastname1
            )

        [16] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname6
                [1] => lastname6
            )

        [17] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname20
                [1] => lastname20
            )

        [18] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname14
                [1] => lastname14
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname5
                [1] => lastname5
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Could you use `var_export` to represent your input data example? Also provide expected output data example.

Comment: @sectus See expected output data. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to give them new keys, you could create a new one and assign the `$centers` to the original chuncked array. Consider this example: (I think this is from your other post earlier)

```
$centers = array("location1","location2","location3","location4","location5","location6","location7");
$chunked_values = array( array( array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), ), array( array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), ), array( array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), ), array( array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), ), array( array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), ), array( array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), ), array( array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), array( 'firstname13', 'lastname13', 'Armstrong Landscaping', 'state1', 'email13', 'address13', ), ),);
$new_values = array();
foreach($chunked_values as $key => $value) {
    $new_values[array_shift($centers)] = $value;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_values);
echo '</pre>';
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iqinNb)

Comment: Please check out a follow up to this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146428/dynamically-generate-new-multidimensional-arrays-in-a-for-loop